# Trying to Sort in Java 8 with Nulls in the Data

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am trying to sort a list that I get by the comparator given. I am passing the comparator through the NullsLast method to get a Null-Friendly version of my comparator like the JavaDoc states. However, when I run the code I am still getting a Null Pointer Exception when I pass a String comparator to the method.

```
private <T> void sortWithDirection(List<T> details, boolean isAscending, Comparator<T> comparator){

    if(isAscending){
        details.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(comparator));
    } else {
        details.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(comparator.reversed()));
    }
}

List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>();
sortWithDirection(users, false, Comparator.comparing(UserDTO::getName));
```

Am I using this method wrong? Is there a different way that I can prevent NPEs without removing them from the result set?

Comment: Could you post a stack trace of your NPE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`nullsLast` will handle the case of `UserDTO` being `null`.  It will not save you from `getName` returning `null`.  To handle null names, you would need to apply `nullsLast` before `comparing`:

```
details.sort(comparing(
    UserDTO::getName, 
    nullsLast(naturalOrder())
));
```

or, for reverse order:

```
details.sort(comparing(
    UserDTO::getName, 
    nullsLast(reverseOrder())
));
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought this method worked differently.